# Could we change DropDownList control's displaying style in IE10 the same like in IE9?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, html-select

I have to change the IE 10 dropdownlist style behavior to the same as IE 9, Chrome, Fire Fox. Because in IE 10 it does not show it as a drop down. In IE 10 dropdownlist comes on top of the other controls. Pls refer the attachment for more info.

[image: IE 10 dropdownlist behavior]

I wanna change this style to be same as in other browsers like normal dropdownlist. Any help plz? I still couldn't find a proper solution yet.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can style the browsers selectbox with some CSS but the best way to make it exactly like you want it is to create one yourself using HTML, CSS (and Javascript) or use a plugin like http://www.bulgaria-web-developers.com/projects/javascript/selectbox/

Comment: Thanks for the reply!. dose anyone have sample code for it? by using css, html or java script? Or any clue of how to do it?